# How do I populate a VB.net datagridview combo box properly

Tags: datagridview, combobox

I created a `datagridview` control with a combo box in vb.Net 2008.  In the code below, I retrieve multiple rows of data and configure my `datagrid` to properly show the data.  For all the rows returned, I can populate each row's combo box in the `datagrid` with no problem.

When I try to auto select value(s) when retrieving data for a specific record, all of the combo boxes are incorrectly populated with the same value.

In the code below, 'Populate the Grid Combo' code represents how I load the values into the combo box.  The 'Populate specific record' code is where I believe I'm having the issue. Why is the combo box for all records returned the same value?  I know my loop is correct because non-combo boxes are properly populated.

```vb
'Populate the Grid Combo
            conCombo.Open(sConnectionString)

        'Populate the Referral Reason combo box
        sSQL = "SELECT Referral_Reason_Id, Referral_Reason FROM Referral_Reason WHERE DELETED = FALSE ORDER BY SortOrder"

        cmdCombo = New ADODB.Command
        cmdCombo.ActiveConnection = conCombo
        cmdCombo.CommandText = sSQL
        rsCombo = cmdCombo.Execute

        i = 0
        Do While i < dgPPV.RowCount
            Do While Not rsCombo.EOF
                Dim dgvcc As DataGridViewComboBoxCell
                dgvcc = dgPPV.Rows(i).Cells(3)
                dgvcc.Items.Add(New MyListItem(rsCombo.Fields(1).Value, rsCombo.Fields(0).Value))
                rsCombo.MoveNext()
            Loop
            rsCombo.MoveFirst()
            i = i + 1
        Loop

        If rsCombo.State Then rsCombo.Close()
        If conCombo.State Then conCombo.Close()
        If cmdCombo.State Then cmdCombo.ActiveConnection = Nothing


'Populate specific record
        Sub GetPPVGridData()

        Dim i As Integer

        CloseConnectionString()
        con.Open(sConnectionString)

        sSQL = "SELECT Policy.PolicyDescription, Referral_Reason.Referral_Reason, ERS_Outcome.Outcome_Description, Audit_Outcome.Comment "
        sSQL = sSQL & "FROM ((Audit_Outcome INNER JOIN Referral_Reason ON Audit_Outcome.Referral_Reason_Id = Referral_Reason.Referral_Reason_Id) INNER JOIN Policy ON Audit_Outcome.Policy_Id = Policy.Policy_ID) INNER JOIN ERS_Outcome ON Audit_Outcome.Outcome_Id = ERS_Outcome.Outcome_Id "
        sSQL = sSQL & "WHERE Audit_Outcome.Referral_Id = " & lblReferralId.Text

        cmd = New ADODB.Command
        cmd.ActiveConnection = con
        cmd.CommandText = sSQL
        rs = cmd.Execute

        Do While Not rs.EOF
            For i = 0 To dgPPV.RowCount - 1
                If dgPPV.Rows(i).Cells("dgPPVDescription").Value = rs.Fields(0).Value Then
                    dgPPV.Rows(i).Cells("dgCheckPPV").Value = True
                    dgPPV.Rows(i).Cells("dgPPVDescription").Value = rs.Fields(0).Value
                    dgPPV.Rows(i).Cells("dgPPVReferralReason").Value = rs.Fields(1).Value
                    dgPPV.Rows(i).Cells("dgPPVOutcome").Value = rs.Fields(2).Value
                    dgPPV.Rows(i).Cells("dgPPVComment").Value = rs.Fields(3).Value
                End If
            Next
            rs.MoveNext()
        Loop
        CloseConnectionString()

    End Sub
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the situation.  I changed the way in which I read the values into combo box.  I switched from using what I am comfortable with (record sets) to the datareader.  Much easier and less code.

```
        oConn.Open()
    oCmdSelect.CommandText = "SELECT Referral_Reason_Id, Referral_Reason FROM Referral_Reason WHERE DELETED = FALSE ORDER BY SortOrder"
    oCmdSelect.Connection = oConn
    oReader = oCmdSelect.ExecuteReader

    While oReader.Read
        dgPPVReferralReason.ValueMember = oReader.Item(0)
        dgPPVReferralReason.DisplayMember = oReader.Item(1).ToString
        dgPPVReferralReason.Items.Add(oReader.Item(1).ToString)
    End While

    oConn.Close()
    If oConn.State Then oConn.Close()
```